# Laravel Mix & AngularJS Fails to Load module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and AngularJS 1.7 with laravel-mix but I'm facing issues. Angular fails to load module. Here's my code...

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.scripts([
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'resources/assets/js/admin.js'
], 'public/js/all.js');
```

**admin.js**

```
var app = angular.module("admin", []);

app.controller("AdminController", function($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function(){
        console.log('doing something....');
    }
});
```

I have included an Angular module in the body of the template.

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-red sidebar-mini fixed" ng-app="admin">
```

And mixed js files into the footer of the Blade template.

```
<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="{{asset('admin/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="{{asset('admin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="{{asset('admin/dist/js/adminlte.min.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('js/all.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Optionally, you can add Slimscroll and FastClick plugins.
     Both of these plugins are recommended to enhance the
     user experience. -->
</body>
</html>
```

Then run ...

`npm run dev` or `npm run watch`

However, I'm still getting the same error...

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module admin due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'admin' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or
>   forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.